# Can't use import syntax Error while importing uuid

Tags: node.js, uuid

I am trying to import uuid like

```
import { v1 as uuidv1 } from 'uuid';
```

But I get a syntax error

> Cannot use import statement outside a module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `nodejs` doesn't support `BABEL`!

try:

```
const { v1 as uuid} = require('uuid');
```

If you need `BABEL` you must add it and enable it: look this: 
https://dev.to/ganeshmani/configuring-babel-for-node-js-express-server-35hp
or google it.